# Calculating Running Percentile in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the percentiles from 1:i in a column. For example, for the nth data point, calculate the percentile only using the first n values.

I have tried using `quantile`, but can't seem to figure out how to generalize it.

```
mydata <- c(1, 25, 43, 2, 5, 17, 40, 15, 12, 8)
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output for a specific `n`

Answer (score 0):

```
perc.fn <- function(vec, n){
(rank(vec[1:n], na.last=TRUE) - 1)/(length(vec[1:n])-1)}
```